# How can I get the name of the three reserved file descriptors?

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

I am doing a project for my school where I have to build a shell.

The thing is when I got to do the "open [file] [mode]" command for my shell, I have to keep a list of the opened files with their names, file descriptors and their mode. My problem resides in the fact that I don't know how to actually get the names of those 3 reserved file descriptors to include them in the list (since I have to do it). I know that file descriptor 0 is reserved for standard input, the 1 for standard output and the 2 for standard error output, but I think that if it's possible, I should get their names from some function or library.

I've searched in several sites of internet and I learned a lot of useful things, but I couldn't get a solution for this particular problem, so my last option is asking here and see if someone can enlighten me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, and `STDERR_FILENO` are declared in `unistd.h`.

Comment: There are no filenames for them, just macros that expand into the descriptor numbers.

Comment: Depending on your operating system, `/dev/fd/0` etc. might be filenames you can refer to them by.

Comment: What is the "name" going to be used for? `0`, `1`, and `2` are platform/posix specific file descriptors. `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are the standard `FILE*` you can use.

Comment: Re “I have to keep a list of the opened files with their names, file descriptors and their mode”: Why do you think that?

Comment: POSIX [defines the values](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/unistd.h.html) for `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, and `STDERR_FILENO` as `0`, `1`, and `2`, so there's little gained by using the macros.

Comment: *I have to keep a list of the opened files with their names, file descriptors and their mode* No, you don't. The mode is part of the file descriptor state.  Use [`fcntl( fd, GET_FL, ...)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fcntl.html) to get it directly from the descriptor.  The name doesn't matter as any file can be renamed to a different name or unlinked so it has no name while it's open.

Comment: Use the command ```echo "This is a standard input name: $stdin_name"``` to print a message. To ensure everything is working correctly, repeat the command with ```STDOUT_FILENO``` and ```STDERR_FILENO```. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Karma That's `bash`, the question is about C.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is when I got to do the "open [file] [mode]" command for my shell, I have to keep a list of the opened files with their names, file descriptors and their mode. My problem resides in the fact that I don't know how to actually get the names of those 3 reserved file descriptors to include them in the list (since I have to do it).

Those or any file descriptors do not necessarily *have* names in the sense of file names on the filesystem, nor even device names.  They could be pipe ends, for example.  Those that are associated with a regular file at all are not associated with a particular file *name*, as a regular file can have more than one name on the filesystem or none.  The system does not maintain a mapping from file descriptors to file names.  Read the docs of `fstat()`, especially the description of `struct stat`, to find what data the system *does* track for each file descriptor.

You should come up with a substitute to use for these and any other file descriptors your shell inherits.  Maybe a simple placeholder such as `[inherited]`.  If you want to be a little more fancy, you can determine whether a given file descriptor is associated with a terminal device via `isatty()` or (with somewhat more difficulty) by interpreting its device number from a `struct stat` (member `st_dev` / `st_rdev`), and use this to report something different in that case. Or more generally, you could interpret device numbers to give more detailed type information -- "regular file", "terminal", "null device", *etc*..  But there is no good way to get a file name.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want something like this:

```
bool usingstdin = somelogic_using_parameters_and_configuration(argc, argv);

if (usingstdin) {
    // work with stdin
} else {
    // open file(s) at will
    // pay attention to errors
    // work with file(s)
    // close file(s)
}
```

and similar for `stdout` / `stderr`

*Note:* do not close the standard streams!